# Jsoup: Parsing html out of a piece of javascript

Tags: java, jsoup

Does anyone of you know how to get html out of a javascript onmouseover event with Jsoup? That might sound vague, so here is is the code:

```
<table onmouseover="showHoverInfo('', '<a href="somelink"><b>sometext</b>/a><br /> Some other text <br /> <a href="some other link"><b>Some text</b></a>')"
```

And it goes on. What I would like to know, is: how do I get the html code out of the showHoverInfo() method, using Jsoup?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the `onmouseover` attribute via [`.attr()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr%28java.lang.String%29) and then process the obtained string (in the example below I use regex) to get the parameter value you want:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;

public class JSoupGetAttributeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body><div>example</div>" +
        "<table id='myTable' onmouseover=\"showHoverInfo('', '<a href=\\\'somelink\\\'><b>sometext</b>/a><br /> Some other text <br /> <a href=\\\'some other link\\\'><b>Some text</b></a>')\" >" +
        "   <tr>" +
        "       <td>"+
        "       </td>"+
        "   </tr>" +
        "</table>" +
        "</body></html>");
        Element myTable = doc.getElementById("myTable");
        String onmouseover = myTable.attr("onmouseover");
        System.out.println("onmouseover ATTRIBUTE: "+onmouseover);

        /* String processing to get the HTML (second) parameter */
        String secondParameter = null;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("showHoverInfo\\('.*', '(.*?)'\\)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(onmouseover);
        if (m.find()) {
            secondParameter = m.group(1);
        }
        System.out.println("\nHTML PARAMETER: "+secondParameter);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
onmouseover ATTRIBUTE: showHoverInfo('', '<a href=\'somelink\'><b>sometext</b>/a><br /> Some other text <br /> <a href=\'some other link\'><b>Some text</b></a>')

HTML PARAMETER: <a href=\'somelink\'><b>sometext</b>/a><br /> Some other text <br /> <a href=\'some other link\'><b>Some text</b></a>
```

Comment: No, the matcher doesn't find the HTML ATTRIBUTE.

Comment: When you run my example or when you run in your actual page?

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but I have solved my problem in a different way already. I really appreciate your offer!

Comment: Ah, great then! As to the question, why to unaccept it? Didn't it return the html attribute? I'm curious about it.

Comment: No, it didn't return the html attribute.

Comment: Which one didn't? The example code? Or when you brought it to somewhere else?

Comment: When I brought it to somewhere else. The only thing I changed was the html input. It worked until the System.out.println("onmouseover ATTRIBUTE: "+onmouseover); part, and after that, it stopped working. Strange, isn't it?

Comment: What was the HTML input you used? Maybe you have to change it a bit. The code was intended only to be a demonstration - it will probably have to be adapted.

Comment: Possible. But that doesn't matter anymore. I would appreciate it if you had a look at this question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503814/jsoup-local-file-parsing-throws-ioexception> Everbody says the path is incorrect, but it isn't.

Comment: Hm.. I'm still baffled as to why you unaccpted the answer, since the specific part of html could be parsed out (with the example to show). If it does not seem to wor, maybe you could provide the HTML you used, so we get the point of this question through. (About the other question, it looks deleted when I click it.)